# In R: How to return the length of a sound?

Tags: r

I am looking to find out the length of a beep or another sound and would like it to be returned programmatically as a numeric value rather than be displayed on the screen.

`library(beepr) beep(sound=0)   ### how long is this sound in seconds/milliseconds? beep(sound=5)   ### how long is this sound in seconds/milliseconds?`

Comment: You can calculate that if you divide the length of the data representing that sound (number of samples) by its framerate (number of samples per second).

Comment: Excellent. How do I find out the data length of the data representing the sound and how do I find its framerate? That should give me the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `soundgen` is a solution. It works with wav/mp3 files.
In this example I assume you have `beepr` installed in its default folder, and I am going to get the duration of beep 1, alias 'microwave_ping_mono.wav`.

```
library(soundgen)
path_to_wav <- 
  paste0(.libPaths()[1],
         "/beepr/sounds/microwave_ping_mono.wav")

sound_length_in_s <- 
   soundgen::analyze(x = path_to_wav)$summary$duration

sound_length_in_s
[1] 1.102993
```

Comment: Very neat solution. Works well. Thank you